# How to load a MANIFEST.MF file into a JAR properly?

Tags: jar, manifest.mf

I don't want to create a 'default manifest file', I just want to load the Manifest file(which I already created as per my requirements) into the JAR as it is. I used the command JAR uf, the MANIFEST.MF is not even loaded into the JAR. And then I tried JAR cvf, the MANIFEST.MF file was loaded with modified data(probably default manifest). What is the correct command to load MANIFEST.MF file into a JAR?

Also, the other files in JAR are .xml, .data, .properties which are all loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For Jar:

```
JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(stream);
Manifest mf = jarStream.getManifest();
```

From servlet its possible to use also:

```
try(InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")) {
          return ....;
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for a cmd JAR command. Can you kindly help with that, if possible?

Comment: try from command line: `unzip -p app.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: @Adharsh is that you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @AntonZ. Thanks for that. But I was looking for a command to load a manifest as it is. Jar cfm worked for me. The manifest is loaded as it is without modifying it to be the default manifest.